# PHP preg_match needed to ensure only ONE space character is allowed between words

Tags: php, regex

basically I need a preg_match that ensures that only one space character is allowed between each word (IF there is more than one word).

My existing rule is:

```
(^[A-Za-z\s]+$)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If there is never a case when you'd allow more than one space, say between sentences, you could just substitute *all* multiple spaces with a single space and not worry about their proximity to words.  e.g. `/{SPACECHAR}+/{SPACECHAR}/`. (I used '{SPACECHAR}' instead of a blank space to make it obvious what I mean.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "word", but assuming you mean letters in A-Z or a-z you can try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

Note that `\s` does *not* mean the space character - it means any whitespace, including a new line.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[\S]+\s?[^\s]?/i
```

Will search for any word with one space after it and not a space after that one space

```
/\s?\S+\s/
```

Will search for any character with whitespace on either side or only on the end.

Comment: The first regex works, but when there is only one word (with no leading/trailing spaces) it fails on that too.

Comment: `/^[\S]+\s?[^\s]?/` matches a string that starts with one or more non-whitespace characters--that's all.  *If* they're followed by a whitespace character the `\s?` will match it, and if *that's* followed by a non-whitespace character the `[^\s]?` will match it.  But neither of your regexes will *prevent* a match of two or more consecutive spaces.

Comment: `/^[\S]+\s?[^\s]?/` says if there is a whitespace after a non-whitespace character force it to be only one, otherwise do not match.  That sounds exactly like what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

i think to specify a number of occurences to your match you put i.e{1} {1,5} (to match only 1 or between 1 and 5 inclusive) so something like...

^[A-Za-z]+( {1})$

Comment: also, doesn't the \w flag match words?

Comment: That works but is unimportant in regular expressions unless you want to repeat.  All regular expressions assumes one match per character in line, this means the {1} is just redundant.