# Regex in PHP that allows alphanumeric with one space only

Tags: php, regex, alphanumeric

How can I build a regex that allows alphanumeric and only one space like :

```
MM56M pass
MM 54M pass
MMM 5
555555 pass
LPOLKG pass
MM 5T YU does not pass
```

Thanks

Comment: See [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970).

Comment: why not  simply count the spaces and check, if more then 1? (without regex)

Comment: I need it too as alphanumeric

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)... https://regex101.com/r/hQ6fM4/2..

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287602/php-preg-match-needed-to-ensure-only-one-space-character-is-allowed-between-word

Comment: Sorry it is not a duplicate topic the answer given is not working for ZZZ Z ZZ as string , there is 2 spaces and the regex ^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*$ does not check that. you can test here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: `echo (trim($str, "a..zA..Z0..9") === " ") ? ☺ :  "(⊙＿⊙)"; `

Comment: What is that? a new language :)

Comment: If `ZZZ Z ZZ` is a valid string your question doesn't cover that..

Answer (score 1):

Would this work:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)?$
```

It matches one or more any-case letters or numbers then possibly a space and one or more any-case letters or numbers

Comment: You would also want to anchor the the start/end of the string or else this will just match any substring and pass validation. Also, OP doesn't say, but is the space required.

Comment: my bad, hopefully fixed it @oussamakamal

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work...

```
/^[[:alnum:]]+( [[:alnum:]]+)?$/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hQ6fM4/2 (not the `g` modifier being used here won't be used in PHP, if the string is multi-lined use the `m` so the `^$` affect each line).

The `[[:alnum:]]` is a posix character bracket for an alpha or numerical character. The `+` after is a quantifier meaning one or more of those characters. The `^$` are anchors the `^` is the start of the string, the `$` is the ending. The `()` is a grouping and the `?` after makes that whole second group optional. The `/` are delimiters telling where the regex starts and ends.

or if you want a strange approach:

```
$str = 'test test';
$post = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $str);
if (((strlen($str) - 1) == strlen($post) || (strlen($str) == strlen($post))) && ctype_alnum($post)) {
echo  'tis good';
} else {
 echo 'rut row';
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/505494